# Python threading, passing a variable you just created

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Is there a way to declare and pass a thread at the same time. e.g

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(t1))
```

This may seem weird but i want to use the `t1.join()` method however i do not want to do this in my main scope because the processes inside t1 are lengthy and using the `join()` method in the main scope stop some UI interface changes which only happen at the end of the function(main scope). So really what I'm asking is, is there a way to let the function creating the thread perform all its processes without having to wait for the functions with in the thread to complete while still being able the use the `join()` method at some point, because the functions that come after the function the calls the thread behave weirdly if we don't call the join method on t1

Comment: You can call the `join` method whenever you want or not at all.  Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Well my understanding of join is that it waits for all threads to complete, than the rest of the code can continue. If i wait in my main thread the code stops entirely, if i try to join within one of the threads it throw an error saying i cannot join at that point which makes sense because, how can the code within one function wait for code in another function, those 2 blocks of code never get to a point of being linear again. At some point my code has to be linear again

Comment: `join` waits for one thread to complete, not all threads.  Having one function wait for code in another function isn't inherently problematic.  Unfortunately, I still don't understand the problem.  It looks like you asked:  If thread A starts thread B, can thread A then do things other than immediately wait for thread B to end, while still being able to wait for thread B to end at some later time?  If that's the question, the answer is "yes."

Comment: Yes you definitely put it better than i did, In my my situation thread A would represent the main thread. How might i go about doing this?

Comment: In the main thread, start thread B and don't call `join` on it.  In thread B, do some useful work and eventually exit.  It can exit by returning from the function.  In the main thread, after starting thread B, do other useful work and maintain the user interface.  At some later point, when you no longer want the main thread to be operating in parallel with thread B and the main thread can be blocked, have the main thread call `join` on the thread B object.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I guess this can work too, however i found a way around it. I created a button in the main thread that would not appear on the screen till thread B was done, Because i add the button to the interface inside of the thread, than in the main thread i bind the button to a function that joins the thread, therefore the main thread can perform all its operations without being held up by the thread B and only once the button is clicked the rest of the code can run linear again. I appreciate your help though